# How do I get jquery tablesorter to sort like sql server/entity?

Tags: jquery, sql-server, tablesorter

So I using custom parser to try and get tablesorter to sort like sql server.  The data I am returning from entity call can be max 50 characters (varchar(50)).

Here is my parser code:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    // set a unique id 
    id: 'entitySort',
    is: function (s) {
        // return false so this parser is not auto detected 
        return false;
    },
    format: function (s) {
        // format your data for normalization 

        // remove any special characters that are not alphabet or number
        return s.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9]/g, '');
    },
    // set type, either numeric or text 
    type: 'text'
});
$('#headerTable').tablesorter({
    headers: {
        0: { sorter: 'entitySort' }
    },
    widthFixed: false,
    widgets: ["stickyHeaders"],
    widgetOptions: {
        // css class name applied to the sticky header
        stickyHeaders: "tablesorter-stickyHeader",
        stickyHeaders_addResizeEvent: true
    }
});
```

Here is a sample of the data that is returned via entity call:

```
1190001676346NB
1910-AM
309AMXG_QP
309CMXG_533: LA-C130/AS057-2222
523:2.9
523PAA2.15
526PAH2.33/ROTOR-76696A
AMXG-QP
```

First thing I did was remove all special characters on the data thinking that would help to sort:

```
1190001676346NB
1910AM
309AMXGQP
309CMXG533LAC130AS0572222
52329
523PAA215
526PAH233ROTOR76696A
AMXGQP
```

However the tablesorter always wants to sort by number size first on text or numeric

```
309AMXGQP
309CMXG533LAC130AS0572222
523PAA215
526PAH233ROTOR76696A
1910AM
52329
1190001676346NB
AMXGQP
```

I tried padding the end of the strings with '0' to get them all the same length. I tried changing type of sort to numeric, alphanumeric and nothing is working to sort the same as sql server.  I realize the data is intensive to sort.  I am desperate for help!

Comment: I think if you want to emulate SQL Server sorting you're going to be in for a ride. Have you considered server side sorting?

Comment: Using an API to pull large amounts of data to client side.  Sorting server side defeats the purpose unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`textSorter` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#textsorter) to change the way a column is sorted. [Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/1741/):

```js
$('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    // custom text sorter
    textSorter: {
        // text sorter for the first column only
        0 : function(a, b){
            return a > b ? 1 : (a < b ? -1 : 0);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Mottie, can I run that textSorter option inside my "parser" after replacing special characters? Or will it handle special characters? Dont you have your own version of tablesorter? Should I be using that? Apologize for late response, apparently work decided I no longer need access to stackoverflow.

Comment: The parser is just that, it parses data, no sorting. The original tablesorter doesn't have an alphanumeric sorter, so you shouldn't need to define the textSorter (it's not an option in the original anyway).